# Comparar hora atual com hora registada no banco de dados?

Tags: php

Eu tenho uma hora registada no banco de dados e gostaria de a comparar com a hora atual. Como devo fazê-lo com `PHP`?

A razão disso é que eu precisava de selecionar um valor que estivesse disponível numa certa hora.

Os campos que eu tenho são:

- hora_inicio em time()
- hora_fim em time()

E precisava que selecionasse um dos valores da base de dados que estivesse dentro da hora.

Comment: qual o banco? você quer selecionar na *query* ou comparar no código `php`?

Comment: Vc quer saber se o horario atual está entre os dois horarios que estão no banco?

Comment: Sim, é possivel?

Comment: é sim, veja se a resposta q eu postei te atende

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu fiz de uma forma no qual consegui sozinho.

Primeiro fiz um loop por todos os dados da tabela e procedi à comparação de horas.

```
$select = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM programas");
while($mos2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)){
    $str_inicio=strtotime($mos2['hora_inicio']);
    $str_fim=strtotime($mos2['hora_fim']);
    $str_atual=strtotime($hora_toda);
    $diferenca=$str_fim-$str_atual;
    if($str_atual > $str_inicio && $str_atual < $str_fim){
        $variavel = $mos2['id'];
    }
}
```

Com isto, ele devolverá o que tem o `id` que desejo para apresentar asseguir.

```
$select2=mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM programas where id = '".$variavel."'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($select2)){
$mos=mysqli_fetch_assoc($select2);

$radio = $mos['hora_inicio']." - ".$mos['hora_fim'];

echo $mos['img'].",".$mos['nome'].",".$radio.",".str_replace(" ", "_", $mos['nome']);
}
```

**Nota:** O último `echo` é usado pessoalmente mais à frente no código por isso não ser necessário explicação.

Answer (score 1):

No lugar de `$inip` e `$fimp` vc deve colocar o horario que está no seu banco de dados:

```
$QUERY = SELECT * FROM BANCO.TABELA;
$EXECUTE_QUERY = mysqli_query($conexao, $QUERY);
$DATA = mysqli_fecth_array($EXECUTE_QUERY);
$inip = $DATA['hora_inicio'];
$fimp = $DATA['hora_fim'];

$startP = $inip;
$endP   = $fimp;
$now    = time();//Hora atual

if($startP <= $now && $now <= $endP){
    echo "Dentro do horario";
} else {
    echo "Fora do horario";
}
```

Comment: o formato de tempo que ele questionou é `time()` que é um valor inteiro.

Comment: @RFL Não tinha me atentado a isso, acho q a alteração acima deve resolver então